# Function get_home_url appends dot

Tags: home-url

Does anyone have this problem? When I call this function on my mobile theme, it appends a dot at the end of my home url, so it looks like www.example.com. which makes some other functions work improperly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Turn off all plugins, switch back to the default theme. Does that still happen?

Comment: If it continues to happen, please enable [debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).